# Mount Lightband with Screws into Helicoils?

Tags: launch, structural-design, vibration

Quick question; provided sufficient rigidity and accommodation for tear out in the underlying structure, can you fasten a Planetary Systems Motorized (or Advanced) Mark 2 lightband ESPA interface with appropriately sized screws into locking helicoils?   Or do you need through-bolts?

Thanks!

- https://www.planetarysystemscorp.com/product/mark-ii-motorized-lightband/

Comment: https://www.planetarysystemscorp.com/contact-us/